# how to get the values from input fields dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

i have a page in my website that has a form that conatains inputs fields, i also have a button that creates more input fields incase the user needs to inputs more things. the problem now is that if the user makes a mistake and creates inputs feilds that he/she doe not need he can remove them but this creates a problem when inserting the value of the input fields in the database. i am using a for loop to get all the value of the input fields by id eg. id1, id2, id3 etc, but if the user removes one of the inputs field for example id2, i cant get id3 becuase the for loop will still run normally from 1 too the end and will not skip 2.

here is the code to create more input feilds:

```
let counter = 1;

document.getElementById("shownew").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // new_section.style.display = "flex";
  new_section.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 
  `   <div class="lowerlayer2" id="close${counter}">
  <button id="delete" onclick="deleteme(${counter})"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Word Type" id="wtype${counter}" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Synonym" id="syn${counter}" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Antonyms" id="anty${counter}" />

  <textarea
    cols="30"
    rows="10"
    placeholder="History & Etymology"
    id="history${counter}"
  ></textarea>
  <textarea
    cols="30"
    rows="10"
    placeholder="Examples"
    id="example${counter}"
  ></textarea>
  <textarea
    cols="30"
    rows="10"
    placeholder="Definition 1"
    id="def1${counter}"
  ></textarea>
  </div>`
  );
  counter++;
});
```

here is the code to delete the input feilds:

```
function deleteme(id) {
  document.getElementById(`close${id}`).style.display="none";
  document.getElementById(`close${id}`).innerHTML="";
  counter--
}
```

here is the code to get the values from the values of input fields:

```
document.getElementById("wan").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  type = "";
  syn = "";
  anty = "";
  history = "";
  example = "";
  def1 = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    type += document.getElementById(`wtype${i}`).value + "^";
    syn += document.getElementById(`syn${i}`).value + "^";
    anty += document.getElementById(`anty${i}`).value + "^";
    history += document.getElementById(`history${i}`).value + "^";
    example += document.getElementById(`example${i}`).value + "^";
    def1 += document.getElementById(`def1${i}`).value + "^";
  }
  console.log(
    type +
      " . " +
      syn +
      " . " +
      anty +
      " . " +
      history +
      " . " +
      example +
      " . " +
      def1
  );
});
```

Comment: I see no other option here. Use a try catch block inside the for loop. Note the input field number for which the exception is thrown here and be sure to skip that field, when populating the database.

Comment: @revmatcher thanks that might work

Comment: use array index to delete the row instead of class + index. and iterate the complete DOM to fill the values in array/object on click. That won't throw error.
Or if you aren't able to follow this approach, you can provide a partially working codesand box or another URL I can make change there.

Comment: @revmatcher i tried the try catch block, but i want the loop to keep running even after it catches the error how do i do that?

Comment: @CurtisCrentsil Umm, I'm not sure what you mean. The try catch block is inside the for loop, right? Could you post that code here as well?